# Unable to enable datepicker field after disabling

Tags: jquery

I've written the following code to disable a return date field from an itinerary if a 'one-way' checkbox is clicked.

Problem is, it works on jsFiddle, but not when the input field is a jQuery DatePicker field, which I'd like it to be.

```
$('#returndate_true').click(function(){
    $('#returndate').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#returnflex').removeAttr("disabled");
});

$('#returndate_false').click(function(){
    $('#returndate').attr("disabled",true);
    $('#returnflex').attr("disabled",true);
});

<span><input type="radio" value="true" name="traveltype" id="returndate_true"><label for="returndate_true" class="collection_radio_buttons">Return-trip</label></span><span><input type="radio" value="false" name="traveltype" id="returndate_false"><label for="returndate_false" class="collection_radio_buttons">One-way</label></span>
                <input class="cdate" name="date_return" size="13" id="returndate" disabled="disabled" />
                <select id="returnflex" name="return_flex" disabled="disabled">
                    <option value="no flex">No Flexibility</option>
                    <option value="plusmin 1day">+/- 1 day</option>
                    <option value="plusmin 2days">+/- 2 days</option>
                    <option value="plusmin 3days">+/- 3 days</option>
                    <option value="same week">Same Week</option>
                </select></font></b>
```

[Check out the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/wK6Y4/). (stripped it down to the essentials).

Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks in advance,
Sh.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/wK6Y4/1/

Comment: check the jQuery versions you are using

Comment: Thanks.
As I said, it works fine in jsFiddle, but not when the field is a jQuery DatePicker field. (I'm not sure how to simulate this in jsFiddle).

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.9.1.

Comment: @ShamaiWeinberger Check the fiddle I posted.. it has a datepicker on the `returndate` input

Comment: @billyonecan:
Thanks, indeed it works. But it isn't working on my site, how could that be?
You've only added the  $('#returndate').datepicker();  line, correct?

Comment: You've only added the 

$('#returndate').datepicker(); 

line, correct?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yeah, that was the only thing I added

Comment: @ShamaiWeinberger you expect your datepicker to work without initialisation?

Comment: Ok, but when I implement it on my site, it just stays disabled since the beginning, and I can't seem to enable it.
In the head section, I included jquery-1.9.1.js, jquery-ui.js and datepicker.js.
Can anyone figure out why it doesn't work please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a quick look at your code, the reason it isn't working is because the code isn't inside of the `$(document).ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#returndate_true').click(function(){
        $('#returndate').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#returnflex').removeAttr("disabled");
    });

    $('#returndate_false').click(function(){
        $('#returndate').attr("disabled",true);
        $('#returnflex').attr("disabled",true);
    });

    $('#returndate').datepicker();

});
```

This is the [first thing you learn about jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/). Placing your code inside of this function ensures that the DOM is fully loaded before manipulating any of its contents.